# Change asp.net form view to insert mode from another page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have 2 ASP.NET pages written in ASP.NET Web Froms . 
    On Page 1 I have the Main Grid View Control . 
On Page 2 I have details listed within a From View control.

I have a button on Page 1 . On clicking the button . I would like to change the 
    From View Mode to Insert. Is there a way I can do it ?

I have my code below :

**Page 1 :** ASPX page : Button & Grid View

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnNewIssue" Text="Create New Issue" runat="server" OnClick="btnNewIssue_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
 <asp:Panel>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTasks" runat ="server">
Grid View Code--------------------------------
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Page 2 : ASPX.CS page :

```
 protected void btnNewIssue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = 0;

            What should go here ????



        }

 protected void gvTasks_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Details")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("~/Details.aspx?TaskID=");
                sb.Append(index);

                Response.Redirect(sb.ToString());

                //Response.Redirect("~/Details.aspx?TaskID=1234");

            }

    }
```

Page 2 : aspx Form View

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
---Item Template Code....
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
--- Edit Item Template Code....
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
--- Insert Item Template Code....
</InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

page 2 : aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                FillFormView();
            }
        }

   private void FillFormView()
        {
           int taskid = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["TaskID"]);

            ----- Fetch dlist from Service based on taskid-----
            FormView1.DataSource = dlist;
            FormView1.DataBind();
}



protected void FormView1_ModeChanging(Object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.NewMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
            {
                Label lblTaskId = ((Label)FormView1.FindControl("lblTaskID"));
                Label lblTaskTitle = ((Label)FormView1.FindControl("lblTaskTitle"));   
                FormView1.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
                FillFormView();
            }
            else
            {
                FormView1.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
                FillFormView();
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `FillFormView` function

```
private void FillFormView()
    {

       var taskId = Request.QueryString["TaskID"];

       if (taskId == null){
           FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
           return;
       }

       FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
       /// dlist from Service based on taskid-----
       FormView1.DataSource = dlist;
        FormView1.DataBind();
}
```

there is no ned for `FormView1_ModeChanging` function.

One more thing, use string.Format instead of StringBuilder class

```
protected void gvTasks_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Details")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Details.aspx?TaskID={0}", index));
            //Response.Redirect("~/Details.aspx?TaskID=1234");

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnNewIssue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect("~/Details.aspx");
}
```

or You can use an anchor tag instead of button.

```
<a href="Details.aspx">Create New Issue</a>
```

in your FillForView or You can also use #Cruiser-KID Answer

```
private void FillFormView()
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TaskID"])){
       FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
   }
   else
   {
       int taskid = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["TaskID"]);
       FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
       ----- Fetch dlist from Service based on taskid-----
       FormView1.DataSource = dlist;
       FormView1.DataBind();
   }
}
```